# Error with devise-security email validation: Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My application authentication is based on Devise. My customer now requires more security with passwords and registration emails management, so I installed the **devise-security** gem. As recommended in the ***E-Mail Validation*** topic of the wiki, I also added the **email_address** gem.

Here is the Gemfile:

```
# Authentication and Authorisations
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-security'
gem 'email_address' # for email validation
gem 'cancancan', '~> 3.0'
```

The User model contains:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
extend CsvHelper
  validates_with EmailAddress::ActiveRecordValidator, field: :email

  # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
  # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
  attr_accessor :login

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
            :trackable, :secure_validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :password_archivable

  ### validations
  #validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
```

config/initializers/devise.rb contains:

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # config.secret_key = 'a49a0d923cf906a896ff86cc42273cd1cfb578a6f3123173f7631c51b0ed8eea6233a0fc832d1dc1ea733b6f1f5e31b25d4c8d670641a64af76dad8690f00bf2'

  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  config.mailer_sender = 'SIS@bfs.admin.ch'

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

  # Configure the parent class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'

  # ==> ORM configuration
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  config.authentication_keys = [:login]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication.
  config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  # By default Devise will store the user in session.
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11

  # Send a notification to the original email when the user's email is changed.
  config.send_email_changed_notification = false

  # Send a notification email when the user's password is changed.
  config.send_password_change_notification = false

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  config.confirm_within = 1.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. 
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  config.confirmation_keys = [:email]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  config.remember_for = 1.days

  # Invalidates all the remember me tokens when the user signs out.
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = false

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 6..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. 
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  config.unlock_keys = [:email]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  config.unlock_strategy = :email

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  config.maximum_attempts = 3

  # Warn on the last attempt before the account is locked.
  config.last_attempt_warning = true

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
  # reset. 
   config.sign_in_after_reset_password = true

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # config.scoped_views = false

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden..
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
    end
```

config/initializers/devise-security.rb contains:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Security Extension
  # Configure security extension for devise

  # Should the password expire (e.g 3.months)
  config.expire_password_after = 1.year

  # Need 1 char of A-Z, a-z and 0-9
  config.password_complexity = { digit: 1, lower: 1, symbol: 1, upper: 1 }

  # How many passwords to keep in archive
  config.password_archiving_count = 10

  # Deny old passwords (true, false, number_of_old_passwords_to_check)
  # Examples:
  # config.deny_old_passwords = false # allow old passwords
  # config.deny_old_passwords = true # will deny all the old passwords
  # config.deny_old_passwords = 3 # will deny new passwords that matches with the last 3 passwords
  config.deny_old_passwords = true

  # enable email validation for :secure_validatable. (true, false, validation_options)
  # dependency: see https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/blob/master/README.md#e-mail-validation
  config.email_validation = true
end
```

Since I add **:secure_validatable**, the Puma server refuses to start and raises the following error:

> C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.4.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:121:in
>   `rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator'
>   (ArgumentError)

What did I miss with configuration of this validation feature?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please add `email_validation: false` to user.rb as:
`
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
            :trackable, :secure_validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :password_archivable, email_validation: false

`

Comment: I commented out the validates :email line, but the issue still raises. I provided also the devise.rb file in case it contains more clues...

Comment: I have tested on local, the email validation is working. some random domain does not work and gmail.com works.This error is generated:  Email Invalid Email Address when I used a random m@hafkl12.com email address. When i used my Gmail email it worked.

Comment: EmailValidator was getting called as devise was still looking for default email validator.

Comment: Do you rely on an external validator as gem 'email_address' ? Is there more to configure than validates_with ?

Comment: I haven't used the email_address, just to get the same error i tried setting up a rails app in this way and then was able to fix ir.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, which we all need to know.

We don't need to mention `email_validation: false` as it will not validate **emails** and **password** for `secure_validatable` if the value would be `false`

Your Model class should look like this -> ***app/model/user.rb***.

```rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :secure_validatable
```

Be sure, no other **format** validation should be there for an email in **user.rb**. Eg:

```rb
validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP}
```

Other than the format validation is okay to have. Eg:

```rb
validates :email, presence: { message: "Email can't be blank" }, uniqueness: { message: "This email is already registered with us. Please check again and puts your email address." }
```

Now the real game begins, you have to create a new validator file -> ***app/validators/email_validator.rb***

**NOTE** - Don't change the function name `validate` in `EmailValidator` class, although you can change the inner functionality according to you.

```rb
require 'uri'

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.email.match? URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP
      return
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      record.errors[:email] << 'has an invalid format'
    end
  end
end
```

Also, now you can comment out the line from ***config/initializers/devise.rb***, as now it's not using this email regex config anymore from devise.

```rb
# config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
```

The ***config/initializers/devise_security.rb*** should look like the below to use `secure_validatable` properly.

**NOTE**

- You don't need to worry about the `config.email_validation` to be `true` as it's default value in `devise_security` gem is `true`
- Also, you don't need to worry for `config.password_complexity = { digit: 1, lower: 1, symbol: 1, upper: 1 }` as the default complexity already sets the value 1 for everything.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Security Extension
  # Configure security extension for devise

  # Should the password expire (e.g 3.months)
  # config.expire_password_after = false

  # Need 1 char each of: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and a punctuation mark or symbol
  # You may use "digits" in place of "digit" and "symbols" in place of
  # "symbol" based on your preference
  config.password_complexity = { digit: 1, lower: 1, symbol: 1, upper: 1 }

  # How many passwords to keep in archive
  # config.password_archiving_count = 5

  # Deny old passwords (true, false, number_of_old_passwords_to_check)
  # Examples:
  # config.deny_old_passwords = false # allow old passwords
  # config.deny_old_passwords = true # will deny all the old passwords
  # config.deny_old_passwords = 3 # will deny new passwords that matches with the last 3 passwords
  # config.deny_old_passwords = true

  # enable email validation for :secure_validatable. (true, false, validation_options)
  # dependency: see https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/blob/master/README.md#e-mail-validation
  # config.email_validation = true

  # captcha integration for recover form
  # config.captcha_for_recover = true

  # captcha integration for sign up form
  # config.captcha_for_sign_up = true

  # captcha integration for sign in form
  # config.captcha_for_sign_in = true

  # captcha integration for unlock form
  # config.captcha_for_unlock = true

  # captcha integration for confirmation form
  # config.captcha_for_confirmation = true

  # Time period for account expiry from last_activity_at
  # config.expire_after = 90.days

  # Allow password to equal the email
  # config.allow_passwords_equal_to_email = false
end
```

The code is perfectly fine now to use the `secure_validatable` for your model.

Reference of my answer - https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/issues/77#issuecomment-1405101158